# Broken jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have a problem with a jQuery javascript slider.

Basically I have a problem with a slider on this site http://crearewebsites.co.uk/victoria/pb-metal-dev/

It's called orbit slider available from http://www.zurb.com/playground/orbit-jquery-image-slider, I've tried searching their documentation etc but no help there.

The problem is that when the page is first loaded all of the slides flash through really quickly then it gets stuck on the first slide for 2 cycles before working properly.

Also is there a way to force it behind the image container as the rounded corners should cover the slides when it animates.

Any help even the slightest would be much appreciated, cheers!

Here is the code im using to call the slider:

```
<script src="js/jquery.orbit-1.2.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(window).load(function() {
   $('#slider').orbit({
  'timer': true,
  'advanceSpeed': 6000,     
  'bullets' : false,        
  'bulletThumbs': false,
 });
```

The HTML

```
  <div id="slider-container">
     <div id="slider" class="png-fix">
        <img src="Images/energy-efficient-powder-coating-equipment.png" class="png-fix slide-img" alt="PB Metal Finishing Spray Save System" /> 
        <img src="Images/experts-in-powder-coating-equipment.png" class="png-fix slide-img" alt="Experts in Powder Coating Equipment" />
        <img src="Images/complete-turnkey-modular-powder-coating-plant-solutions.png" class="png-fix slide-img" alt="Complete modular, turnkey powder coating plant solutions." />
```

Think it might be something in the JavaScript code:

---

```
(function(e) {
        e.fn.orbit = function(a) {
                a = e.extend({
                    animation: "horizontal-push",
                    animationSpeed: 600,
                    timer: true,
                    advanceSpeed: 4E3,
                    pauseOnHover: false,
                    startClockOnMouseOut: false,
                    startClockOnMouseOutAfter: 1E3,
                    directionalNav: true,
                    captions: true,
                    captionAnimation: "fade",
                    captionAnimationSpeed: 600,
                    bullets: false,
                    bulletThumbs: false,
                    bulletThumbLocation: "",
                    afterSlideChange: function() {}
                }, a);
                return this.each(function() {
                            function t() {
                                if (!a.timer || a.timer == "false") return false;
                                else if (u.is(":hidden")) v = setInterval(function() {
                                    o("next")
                                }, a.advanceSpeed);
                                else {
                                    r = true;
                                    A.removeClass("active");
                                    v = setInterval(function() {
                                        var d = "rotate(" + p + "deg)";
                                        p += 2;
                                        w.css({
                                            "-webkit-transform": d,
                                            "-moz-transform": d,
                                            "-o-transform": d
                                        });
                                        if (p > 180) {
                                            w.addClass("move");
                                            B.addClass("move")
                                        }
                                        if (p > 360) {
                                            w.removeClass("move");
                                            B.removeClass("move");
                                            p = 0;
                                            o("next")
                                        }
                                    }, a.advanceSpeed / 180)
                                }
                            }

                            function q() {
                                if (!a.timer || a.timer == "false") return false;
                                else {
                                    r = false;
                                    clearInterval(v);
                                    A.addClass("active")
                                }
                            }

                            function C() {
                                if (!a.captions || a.captions == "false") return false;
                                else {
                                    var d = c.eq(b).data("caption");
                                    if (_captionHTML = e(d).html()) {
                                        l.attr("id", d).html(_captionHTML);
                                        a.captionAnimation == "none" && l.show();
                                        a.captionAnimation == "fade" && l.fadeIn(a.captionAnimationSpeed);
                                        a.captionAnimation == "slideOpen" && l.slideDown(a.captionAnimationSpeed)
                                    } else {
                                        a.captionAnimation == "none" && l.hide();
                                        a.captionAnimation == "fade" && l.fadeOut(a.captionAnimationSpeed);
                                        a.captionAnimation == "slideOpen" && l.slideUp(a.captionAnimationSpeed)
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            function D() {
                                if (a.bullets) F.children("li").removeClass("active").eq(b).addClass("active");
                                else return false
                            }

                            function o(d) {
                                function g() {
                                    c.eq(m).css({
                                        "z-index": 1
                                    });
                                    x = false;
                                    a.afterSlideChange.call(this)
                                }
                                var m = b,
                                    h = d;
                                if (m == h) return false;
                                if (c.length == "1") return false;
                                if (!x) {
                                    x = true;
                                    if (d == "next") {
                                        b++;
                                        if (b == s) b = 0
                                    } else if (d == "prev") {
                                        b--;
                                        if (b < 0) b = s - 1
                                    } else {
                                        b = d;
                                        if (mb) h = "prev"
                                    }
                                    D();
                                    c.eq(m).css({
                                        "z-index": 2
                                    });
                                    a.animation == "fade" && c.eq(b).css({
                                        opacity: 0,
                                        "z-index": 3
                                    }).animate({
                                        opacity: 1
                                    }, a.animationSpeed, g);
                                    if (a.animation == "horizontal-slide") {
                                        h == "next" && c.eq(b).css({
                                            left: k,
                                            "z-index": 3
                                        }).animate({
                                            left: 0
                                        }, a.animationSpeed, g);
                                        h == "prev" && c.eq(b).css({
                                            left: -k,
                                            "z-index": 3
                                        }).animate({
                                            left: 0
                                        }, a.animationSpeed, g)
                                    }
                                    if (a.animation == "vertical-slide") {
                                        h == "prev" && c.eq(b).css({
                                            top: y,
                                            "z-index": 3
                                        }).animate({
                                            top: 0
                                        }, a.animationSpeed, g);
                                        h == "next" && c.eq(b).css({
                                            top: -y,
                                            "z-index": 3
                                        }).animate({
                                            top: 0
                                        }, a.animationSpeed, g)
                                    }
                                    if (a.animation == "horizontal-push") {
                                        if (h == "next") {
                                            c.eq(b).css({
                                                left: k,
                                                "z-index": 3
                                            }).animate({
                                                left: 0
                                            }, a.animationSpeed, g);
                                            c.eq(m).animate({
                                                left: -k
                                            }, a.animationSpeed)
                                        }
                                        if (h == "prev") {
                                            c.eq(b).css({
                                                left: -k,
                                                "z-index": 3
                                            }).animate({
                                                left: 0
                                            }, a.animationSpeed, g);
                                            c.eq(m).animate({
                                                left: k
                                            }, a.animationSpeed)
                                        }
                                    }
                                    C()
                                }
                            }
                            var b = 0,
                                s = 0,
                                k, y, x, j = e(this).addClass("orbit"),
                                f = j.wrap('').parent();
                            j.add(k).width("1px").height("1px");
                            var c = j.children("img, a img, div");
                            c.each(function() {
                                var d = e(this),
                                    g = d.width();
                                d = d.height();
                                if (g > j.width()) {
                                    j.add(f).width(g);
                                    k = j.width()
                                }
                                if (d > j.height()) {
                                    j.add(f).height(d);
                                    y = j.height()
                                }
                                s++
                            });
                            if (c.length == 1) {
                                a.directionalNav = false;
                                a.timer = false;
                                a.bullets = false
                            }
                            c.eq(b).css({
                                "z-index": 3
                            }).fadeIn(function() {
                                c.css({
                                    display: "block"
                                })
                            });
                            if (a.timer) {
                                f.append('');
                                var u = e("div.timer"),
                                    r;
                                if (u.length != 0) {
                                    var w = e("div.timer span.rotator"),
                                        B = e("div.timer span.mask"),
                                        A = e("div.timer span.pause"),
                                        p = 0,
                                        v;
                                    t();
                                    u.click(function() {
                                        r ? q() : t()
                                    });
                                    if (a.startClockOnMouseOut) {
                                        var E;
                                        f.mouseleave(function() {
                                            E = setTimeout(function() {
                                                r || t()
                                            }, a.startClockOnMouseOutAfter)
                                        });
                                        f.mouseenter(function() {
                                            clearTimeout(E)
                                        })
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            a.pauseOnHover && f.mouseenter(function() {
                                q()
                            });
                            if (a.captions) {
                                f.append('');
                                var l = f.children(".orbit-caption");
                                C()
                            }
                            if (a.directionalNav) {
                                if (a.directionalNav == "false") return false;
                                f.append('RightLeft');
                                var n = f.children("div.slider-nav").children("span.left"),
                                    z = f.children("div.slider-nav").children("span.right");
                                n.click(function() {
                                    q();
                                    o("prev")
                                });
                                z.click(function() {
                                    q();
                                    o("next")
                                })
                            }
                            if (a.bullets) {
                                f.append('');
                                var F = e("ul.orbit-bullets");
                                for (i = 0; i "+(i+1)+"
                                    ");if(a.bulletThumbs)if(z=c.eq(i).data("
                                    thumb ")){n=e(''+i+"
                                    ");n.css({background:"
                                    url("+a.bulletThumbLocation+z+") no - repeat "})}e("
                                    ul.orbit - bullets ").append(n);n.data("
                                    index ",i);n.click(function(){q();o(e(this).data("
                                    index "))})}D()}})}})(jQuery);
```

Comment: post the code you are using to call your script. No one wants to dig through your code.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a sample html and it works without glitches.
The images (in my sample) are rendered in the order I declared the `<img />` tag

Where as in your page the image is not rendered that way.Should this be a problem with image loading / caching ?

I tried debugging with firebug/firefox.Your last image is rendered first.

Sample HTML:

```
    <body>
    <div id="imgslider">
        <img src="http://www.lorempixum.com/898/270/animals" alt="" /> 
        <img src="http://www.lorempixum.com/898/270/city" alt="" /> 
        <img src="http://www.lorempixum.com/898/270/food" alt="" /> 
        <img src="http://www.lorempixum.com/898/270/sports" alt="" /> 
    </div>
    <pre>Animals -> City -> Food -> Sports</pre>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(
            function(){
                $('#imgslider').orbit({
            'timer': true,
            'advanceSpeed': 6000,
            'bullets' : false,
            'bulletThumbs': false, 
            });});
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I've checked my HTML markup and I'm pretty sure its all fine, the only difference with yours is that my script tags are inside the head, rather than in the body, would this cause a problem?

Comment: I usually place my code/script that i want to run, after the entire document has been loaded, in the end. 1) Try placing the script at the end. 2) Why do you need 2 versions of JQuery 1.4.2 & 1.6.2 ?     3) Try your slider with more images

Comment: Thank you for continuing trying to help me, I've tried all the steps you suggested but unfortunately to no avail. At least I stripped out an unnecessary version of jQuery ;)

Comment: I meant that `z-index` property of `.slide-img` style class to be removed.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I can't thank you enough for your help, this has been driving me crazy. Cheers so much for your time, you rock!